# Find Lexicographically Greatest Word in a String - C Pointers

Tags: c, algorithm

EDIT: Edited everything sorry for misunderstandings.

I'm trying to write a function to find the **lexicographically greatest word** in a string.

A word is defined as so : contains a letter - can use isalpha() - and does not contain spaces - can use isspace()

If s = "He llo wor  l d  "

s contains the following words : He, llo, wor, l, d.

To find the lexicographically greatest word between two strings, I can use strcmp.

The function prototype is : char *biggestWord(char *s) and it should return the lexicographically greatest word.

I'm literally stuck with it for hours. Here's what I tried to do :

I'm stuck on what to do next. My algorithm idea wouldn't even work if there is two spaces in a row.

```
char *biggestWord(char *s) {
//We will find the first string and compare it to each one of the new strings
//We will keep the value of the higher string everytime
char *res;
char *temp;
int indexStart = 0; //Will contain the index of the first character to then store on temp
int indexEnd = 0; //Will contain the index of the last character to then store on temp
for(int i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++) {
    if(isspace(s[i])) {
        indexEnd = i - 1;
        temp = myStrCpy(s, indexStart, indexEnd); //Will extract the string using start and end index, and put it into temp
        indexStart = i+1;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: *"My objective is to find the biggest ASCII word using strcmp()."* - There is no reason to use `strcmp` in searching for the longest sequence of non-whitespace, alphanumeric characters with a terminated string. So that's going to be a rabbit hole right from the start.

Comment: @WhozCraig Not the longest sequence, I'm looking for the biggest word when comparing everything with strcmp (ie highest ASCII value in a word).

Comment: @Rayan Dev It is unclear whether the function should return the position of the biggest word in a string or a string that represents the biggest word.

Comment: @Rayan Dev You can not apply the function strcmp.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I need to return the string itself as a pointer to char.

Comment: if s = s = "He llo wor l d ", i would need to return "wor" it seems like, because sum of ascii characters seems the highest.

Comment: If "biggest word" doesn't mean "longest word", then your question should clarify what it *does* mean by including a result of your example. Are you saying, given the sequence "z YYYYYYYYYYY", the result is "z" as the "biggest word" ? If so, then I think you mean "lexicographically greatest" word, correct? And case matters (or not) ?

Comment: @RayanDev If you need to return a biggest word as a string then you need to allocate memory dynamically for the string.

Comment: @WhozCraig "lexicographically greatest" exactly thank you

Comment: But the "sum of ascii characters seems the highest", doesnt mean it is the lexicographically greatest word.

Comment: @lulle Then I'm wrong about the ASCII. I want to return the lexicographically greatest using strcmp

Comment: Check out strtok. Store a pointer to the first token in some "greatest word" variable, compare each following token to biggestWord, update it if necessary.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Here is a possible solution:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

char* biggestWord(char* s) 
{
    // Create a buffer for bigest word
    char* buf = calloc(strlen(s) + 1, sizeof(char));
    if (buf == NULL)
        return NULL;
    // Create a buffer for current word
    char* word = malloc(strlen(s) + 1 * sizeof(char));
    if (word == NULL)
        return NULL;

    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; s[i]; i++) {
        if (isspace(s[i])) {
            // We found end of word, replace the space by a nul byte
            strncpy(word, s + j, i - j);
            word[i - j] = 0; // nul terminate
            if (strcmp(buf, word) < 0) {
                // we got a bigger word according to strcmp()
                strcpy(buf, word);
                // skip remaining spaces
                while (s[i] && isspace(s[i]))
                    i++;
                // Remember where a word starts
                j = i;
            }
        }
    }
    free(word);
    return buf;   // cAller must call free()
}

void main(void)
{
    char* res = biggestWord("He llo wor l d ");
    if (res) {
        printf("Result=\"%s\"", res);
        free(res);
    }
}
```

`biggestWord` return a pointer to dynamically allocated string, so it must be freed by caller.

Comment: thank you. Although it is a little hard to understand, it is a correct algorithm and it's what i wanted. Thanks !